# How to use *ngFor with an Object implementing a custom Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, iterator

So I have an Object in a class, which implements an interface

```
interface likertObj {
    1: string | number,
    2: string | number,
    3: string | number,
    4: string | number,
    5: string | number
}

export class LikertValues {
    points: likertObj = {
        1: 'positiveStrong',
        2: 'positive',
        3: 'neutral',
        4: 'negative',
        5: 'negativeStrong'
    }
}
```

In my Component, I create an Instance of this class...

```
  likertValues = new LikertValues();
```

... and try to loop over its properties in my Component template...

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let likertPoint of likertValues.points | keyvalue">
        {{likertPoint.value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

...which works fine on localhost. When I build for production, however, I get the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/[...]: Argument of type 'likertObj' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'Map'.   Type 'likertObj' is
>   missing the following properties from type 'Map':
>   clear, delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.

This error would not arise, when object *points* of class *LikertValues* does not implement my interface LikertObj, meaning when I change my code

```
export class LikertValues {
    points: likertObj = {
        1: 'positiveStrong',
        ...
```

to

```
export class LikertValues {
    points = {
        1: 'positiveStrong',
        ...
```

**What I've tried:**

1. extend my Interface likertObj by Interface Object, which results in the same error
2. extend my Interface likertObj by Interface Map, which results in the intellisense telling me that the object *points* of class *LikertValues*

> is missing the following properties from type 'likertObj': clear,
>   delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.ts(2740)

Now I am thinking that there has to be an easier solution, to make an object both implement a custom interface and be iterable.

(I do not want to spam to much code into this question, so I refrain from adding my build configuration or else here, if it is relevant to be able to answer this question I will edit this post.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the angular pipe `keyvalue`. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4e35e348afaac012f3a3f37a6c15aead6a68efc3/packages/common/src/pipes/keyvalue_pipe.ts).

As you can see, the pipe want: `{[key: string]: V}|Map<string, V>`. Either an object or a map.

So the simpliest solution is to cast the good type.

```
*ngFor="let likertPoint of points | keyvalue"
```

with :

```
get points(): {[key: string]: string} {
   return this.likertValues.points as {[key: string]: string} || {}
}
```

If you have still a problem, try:

```
return (this.likertValues.points as unknow as {[key: string]: string}) || {}
```